# How can get an attribute after map()?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have some JSON output I need to loop through. It's basically a list within a dictionary within a list, etc. Here's an example:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "children": {
        "attachment": {
          "results": [
            {
              "history": {},
              "title": "SomeTitle"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to iterate through the second `results` list (with the `history` and `title`, etc attributes) but I don't know how to get past the `children` attribute. Here's the filter I've tried:

```
results | map(attribute='children').attachment.results
```

It throws an error that the `.attachment.results` doesn't belong after `map()`. So what's the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: The result of `results | map(attribute='children')` is a list hence it does not have any attributes. Since it is not clear what you want as a result, here are several expression which will return some result: `results | map(attribute='children.attachment.results')` -  `results | map(attribute='children.attachment.results') | first` -  `(results | map(attribute='children') | first).attachment.results` -  `(results | map(attribute='children'))[0].attachment.results`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the lookup plugin [*subelements*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements). How exactly you can use it depends on what attributes can change.

- For example, given the list (to demonstrate the iteration let's add one more item to *children.attachment.results*)

```yaml
  results1:
    - children:
        attachment:
          results:
            - history: {}
              title: SomeTitle
            - future: {}
              title: OtherTitle
```

the task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ results1|subelements('children.attachment.results') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.keys()|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=children) => 
  msg:
  - children:
      attachment:
        results:
        - history: {}
          title: SomeTitle
        - future: {}
          title: OtherTitle
  - history: {}
    title: SomeTitle
ok: [localhost] => (item=children) => 
  msg:
  - children:
      attachment:
        results:
        - history: {}
          title: SomeTitle
        - future: {}
          title: OtherTitle
  - future: {}
    title: OtherTitle
```

---

- The above iteration won't work if there are other dictionaries than *children.**. For example,

```yaml
  results2:
    - parents:
        attachment:
          results:
            - history: {}
              title: SomeTitle
            - future: {}
              title: OtherTitle
    - children:
        attachment:
          results:
            - history: {}
              title: SomeTitle
            - future: {}
              title: OtherTitle
```

In this case, convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  results2_keys: "{{ results2|json_query('[][keys(@)]')|flatten(2) }}"
  results2_vals: "{{ results2|json_query('[].*.*.results')|flatten(2) }}"
  results2_dict: "{{ dict(results2_keys|zip(results2_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  results2_dict:
    children:
    - history: {}
      title: SomeTitle
    - future: {}
      title: OtherTitle
    parents:
    - history: {}
      title: SomeTitle
    - future: {}
      title: OtherTitle
```

Use this dictionary to iterate *subelements*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ results2_dict|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=parents) => 
  msg:
  - key: parents
    value:
    - history: {}
      title: SomeTitle
    - future: {}
      title: OtherTitle
  - history: {}
    title: SomeTitle
ok: [localhost] => (item=parents) => 
  msg:
  - key: parents
    value:
    - history: {}
      title: SomeTitle
    - future: {}
      title: OtherTitle
  - future: {}
    title: OtherTitle
ok: [localhost] => (item=children) => 
  msg:
  - key: children
    value:
    - history: {}
      title: SomeTitle
    - future: {}
      title: OtherTitle
  - history: {}
    title: SomeTitle
ok: [localhost] => (item=children) => 
  msg:
  - key: children
    value:
    - history: {}
      title: SomeTitle
    - future: {}
      title: OtherTitle
  - future: {}
    title: OtherTitle
```

---

- To iterate other structures you can try and modify the [*json_query*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) queries.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    results1:
      - children:
          attachment:
            results:
              - history: {}
                title: SomeTitle
              - future: {}
                title: OtherTitle

    results2:
      - parents:
          attachment:
            results:
              - history: {}
                title: SomeTitle
              - future: {}
                title: OtherTitle
      - children:
          attachment:
            results:
              - history: {}
                title: SomeTitle
              - future: {}
                title: OtherTitle

    results2_keys: "{{ results2|json_query('[][keys(@)]')|flatten(2) }}"
    results2_vals: "{{ results2|json_query('[].*.*.results')|flatten(2) }}"
    results2_dict: "{{ dict(results2_keys|zip(results2_vals)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ results1|subelements('children.attachment.results') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.keys()|first }}"

    - debug:
        var: results2_dict

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ results2_dict|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
```

Comment: Thanks! `subelements` seems like a good route, however it's throwing an error "'list object' has no attribute 'title'". This is the filter I'm using: `attachments.json.results | subelements('children.attachment.results')` then in the loop I'm accessing `item.title`, which is throwing the error. I think since the first `results` is a list, when I grab the lower `results`, it's a list of lists. Any way to flatten it into a single list?

Comment: Take a look at *item*. The second element has got the attribute *title*. *`item.title`* is wrong *`item.1.title`* is correct.

Comment: Why would `children.attachment` work but not `item.title`? I didn't include it in the post, but `attachment` also isn't the first attribute under `children`, yet I don't need to use `children.1.attachment`? My loop should be looping the lower `results` array, whereby each `item` in the loop should simply have the attributes: `history`, `title`, etc. Yet for some reason Ansible is reading `item` as a list and I can't figure out why. `results` should be the array that I loop through, thus making each `item` an individual item, but it's being read as a list

Comment: nevermind it worked with `item.1.title`. I don't understand why it worked, but it worked